# I'm having an issue with using ASTParser in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, eclipse-jdt, fastparse

I'm trying to use ASTParser in eclipse but facing an NoClassDefFoundError.
I've already followed some guides and imported related 9 jars.
Following are the details:

```
package test_JDT;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.AST;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnit;
// import org.eclipse.equinox.common.*;

// import org.eclipse.core.jobs;
class tester {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("hello ast parser");
    String javaFilePath = "C:\\Users\\tabzhang\\eclipse-workspace\\test_JDT\\src\\test_JDT/classdemo.java";
    byte[] input = null;
    try {
        BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(javaFilePath));
        input = new byte[bufferedInputStream.available()];
        bufferedInputStream.read(input);
        bufferedInputStream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String str = new String(input);
    System.out.println(str);
    ASTParser astParser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
    astParser.setSource(new String(input).toCharArray());
    astParser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);

    CompilationUnit result = (CompilationUnit) (astParser.createAST(null));
    
    
}
```

}

[included jars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkjdg.png)

[the error report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9b4eD.png)

[command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRHuG.png)

How should I get the code running well?

Comment: This works for me without an error. `ASTParser` should be in the `org.eclipse.jdt.core` JAR. Make sure it's not corrupted by navigating to this class. Please show the command line (in the run configuration there is a _Show Command Line_ button for that).

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply, I also think there shouldn't be an error, it's confusing.
I attch comand line picture in the question case it's too long for comment.

Comment: In _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_, does moving the JARs from the _Modulepath_ to the _Classpath_ help?

Comment: THANKS YOU SO MUCH for your help, Howlger. Moving them to class path does solve the problem. It works well now.

Answer (score 0):

In ***Project > Properties: Java Build Path***, tab ***Libraries* move** all the **JARs from** the ***Modulepath* to** the ***Classpath***.